# How do i properly implement a client side server listener and update ui based on incoming server data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I am trying to create a client which is listening server for data and updating ui based on that.
Also with a button click,client should be able to send message to server etc.

when connect Button is  clicked,i create a serverListener thread which is connecting to server and listening for incoming data(?).

When client is  connected,server sends a data(gamestatus) to client and based on that i am trying to update Ui.(hiding entrance panel and showing lobby panel).I dont know how correct the code is but until there it is working fine,server emits gamestatus data to client and based on that i hide gameEntrance panel and show lobby panel.Also i emit userName data from client to server succesfully inside serverListener.Then for testing i try to emit data from client to server by using trashButtonClick which is in lobbyPanel but seems like i can not access stream therefore i cant send data to server.

```
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();//in trashbuttonclick
```

gives `System.ObjectDisposedException` error.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;



// This is the code for your desktop app.
// Press Ctrl+F5 (or go to Debug > Start Without Debugging) to run your app.

namespace quizclient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ipTextBox.Text = "127.0.0.1";
            portTextBox.Text = "8080";

        }





        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
         async void serverListener(String ip,int port)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(ip); 
        await client.ConnectAsync(IP, port); 

                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    StringBuilder serverStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    string serverString;
                    string clientString;

                    while (client.Connected)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                        int read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (read > 0)
                        {
                            foreach(byte a in buffer)
                            {
                                if (a.Equals(00))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    serverStringBuilder.Append(Convert.ToChar(a).ToString());
                                }


                            }
                            serverString = serverStringBuilder.ToString();
                            if (serverString.All(char.IsDigit))
                            {

                                if (Convert.ToInt32(serverString) == 1)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Game has already started.You cant join.");
                                    break;
                                }
                                else if (Convert.ToInt32(serverString) == 0)
                                {

                                    clientString = "username:" + userNameTextBox.Text;
                                    this.Invoke((Action)delegate () // updating form this might be wrong
                                    {
                                        entrancePanel.Visible = false;
                                        lobbyPanel.Visible = true;
                                    });

                                    Console.WriteLine("sending username to server...");
                                    byte[] sendData = new byte[Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(clientString)];

                                    sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientString);


                                    stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
                                }



                            }



                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                client.Close();
            }


        }

        private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string serverIp = ipTextBox.Text;
            Console.WriteLine(serverIp);
            int port;
            if (!int.TryParse(portTextBox.Text, out port))
            {
                // input wasn't parseable to an integer, show a message perhaps?
            }
            Console.WriteLine(port);
            string userName = userNameTextBox.Text;
            Thread t = new Thread(() => serverListener(serverIp,port));
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();




        }

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void trashButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); //crashes when i press this button.
            byte[] sendData = new byte[Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("testmessagefromclienttoserver")];

            sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testmessagefromclienttoserver");


            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use signalr and save your self a world of hassle

Comment: I wish i can use a library.I have socket.io background but since this is an assignment i am not allowed to use any library

Comment: The message are ASCII and you want to send a terminating character at the end of each message.  When you get the response you check that you get all the character up to the terminating character and then process the message.  It looks like you are using a 0x00 as the terminating character so you can put your processing code before the break after getting the 0x00.